# Windows Batch File Send Email with Filenames based on condition in Body of Message

Tags: windows, command-line, email, powershell, batch

Currently I have a .bat file in Win 7 that has the following:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "emailUserName=x@x.com"
set "emailPassword=x"
set "target=x@x.com"
set "subject=File Changed"
FOR %%G IN ("D:\") DO attrib -A "%%G"
set "body="
FOR %%G IN ("D:\") DO (
    attrib "%%G" | forfiles /P D:\ /m * /d -1 
    )
if not "%body%"=="" echo sending email
if not "%body%"=="" set "body=The following files  @echo %a have been changed:!body!"
if not "%body%"=="" powershell.exe -command "Send-MailMessage -From '!emailUserName!' -to '!target!' -Subject '!subject!' -Body '!body!' -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port '587' -UseSsl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('!emailUserName!', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '!emailPassword!' -AsPlainText -Force)))"

PAUSE
```

In the code above the main problem is I cannot get the output for the following code into the email body or as an attachment:

```
forfiles /P D:\ /m * /d -1
```

The code above is just listing the filenames in the `cmd` but I need those list of filenames to be sent into the body of the email in the first code. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole code inside powershell:

```
@echo off
attrib -A "D:\"
powershell.exe -command "& {$body = forfiles /P D:\ /m * /d -1; $emailUserName = 'Email address'; $emailPassword = 'Password'; $target = 'Recipient Mail'; $subject = 'File changed'; Send-MailMessage -From "$emailUserName" -to "$target" -Subject "$Subject" -Body "$Body" -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port '587' -UseSsl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ("$emailUserName", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$emailPassword" -AsPlainText -Force)))}"
```

Comment: I am getting an error that I am missing parenthesis. I think powershell.exe -command "& {$body - the parenthesis is not closed. I tried putting it in the end but doesnt work. I also tried putting it before $emailUserName and doest work. I tried putting it in the end before closing of the 3 brackets still doesnt work. Where does the } parenthesis go?

Comment: First, you are overcomplicating this. We are here to assist with the Powershell code, which this is not.  You are trying to send bat results. You should convert this to PowerShell code. Create and test the code in Powershell directly, using the ISE or VScode so you get IntelliSense to help and error indicators. Once fully functional, save that as a .ps1 and call that .ps1 from a .bat file or embed it into the bat file. If you are just going to use PowerShell code, then there is no reason to involve batch file code at all, thus simplifying this effort.

Comment: I'm still getting a missing parenthesis error.

Comment: @taberneck fixed it try now

Comment: @postanote thanks for the note, but still Infind it not that complicated.

Comment: @WasifHasan The root problem seems to be $body = forfiles /P D:\ /m * /d -1 - this part provides the results line by line and powershell doesnt like this. Now everything is working except this part, If i change to body to "Hello" then it works perfectly. How would we accept new line entries in the code?